# Unable to loop while ACTION_DOWN event in Android

Tags: android, events

I want to do some continuous tasks in a loop as long the thumb is on my imageview. Once the thumb is up i want to stop that work. For that I am setting a flag on ACTION_DOWN and on ACTION_UP I am cancelling that flag so that the loop may stop. But my loop is getting infinite. Also the Toasts don't show up while looping. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!!

```
      ivThumb.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
                @Override
                public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                    if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                        Toast.makeText(c, "action down", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        ivCharger.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        tvCharging.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        flag = true;
    //                    while (flag){
    //                        Toast.makeText(c, "hello", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    //
    //                    }

                    }
                    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE){
                        Toast.makeText(c, "move", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                    else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                        Toast.makeText(c, "aCTION UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        flag = false;
                        ivCharger.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        tvCharging.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                        //ivBattery.setImageResource(R.drawable.orange);
                    }
 return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What I was doing wrong is I was making my program to loop infinitely in the same thread. It was getting stucked in the loop so couldn't return true for the other events. **Solution** is to give that loop to another thread and returning true in the same thread for other events. Hope it would help others as well. 
Thanks to those who showed their concerns.

```
    ivThumb.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                        ivThumb.setPressed(true);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ACTION_DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        chargingFlag = true;
                        Thread thread = new Thread() {
                            @Override
                            public void run() {
                               while (chargingFlag){

                               }
                            }
                        };

                        thread.start();
//                        while (chargingFlag){
//
//                        }
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ACTION_MOVE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        break;
                    case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                        ivThumb.setPressed(false);
                        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ACTION_UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        chargingFlag = false;
                        break;
                }
                return true;
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2):

Use a `switch` and add the `setPressed` parameter,

```
switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                ivThumb.setPressed(true);
                //Your Function
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                //Your Function
                break;

            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                //Your Function
                ivThumb.setPressed(false);
                invalidate();
                break;
```

This should do the trick. I would recommend calling a function and handling the toasts there.

EDIT:
As, @Chetan pointed out you are return should be `true` to make the `onTouch` work.

Answer (score 1):

Use below code to solve your problem:

You have return `false` from `OnTouchListener` , thats why other events not working I change return value `true` .

```
public static boolean flag = false;
ivThumb.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

switch (event.getAction()) {
 case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
 Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ACTION_DOWN", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
 flag = true;
 new Thread(new Runnable() {
   @Override
   public void run() {
    while (flag) {
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "ACTION_DOWN");
    Log.i(getClass().getSimpleName(), "flag=" + flag);
    }
 }
}).start();

break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ACTION_MOVE", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;

case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
flag = false;
Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "ACTION_UP", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
break;
}

return true;
}
});
```

Comment: Have you return true from onTouch()  method.

Comment: I was already returning true. Also when I remove/comment the loop it works fine.

Comment: no. I have tried switch as well. But adding a loop stops all my events

Comment: Are you doing any UI change in While loop ?

Comment: check my update answer ,if you do not doing any UI operation in while loop.